# how to prevent a UITapGestureRecognizer in a background view from being called when clicking on an overlay

Tags: ios, swift

I have a background dimmedview with a UITapGestureRecognizer. However, when I click on an overlayView, the background UITapGestureRecognizer is called. Is this the intended behavior? Even putting userInteractionEnabled=false on our overlay still has the background UITapGestureRecognizer called. How do I make it so that the overlay prevents the UITapGestureRecognizer on the background view (self.dimmedView) from being called.

Here's the code:

```
func renderOverlayNav(){
  println("YYY about to render outlay")
  self.dimmedView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight))

  self.dimmedView.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
  let dimmedViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("tapOnDimmedView:"))
  self.dimmedView.addGestureRecognizer(dimmedViewTap)


  self.modalView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(50.0, 144.0, (self.screenWidth-100), (self.screenHeight - 200)))
  self.modalView.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
  self.modalView.userInteractionEnabled=false

  let modalScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 200.0))
  modalScrollView.scrollEnabled=true
  modalScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=false

  let closeModalBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0))
  closeModalBtn.titleLabel!.text="x"
  closeModalBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
  self.modalView.addSubview(closeModalBtn)

  let closeModalBtnTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("tapCloseModalBtn:"))
  closeModalBtn.addGestureRecognizer(closeModalBtnTap)
}

func tapOnDimmedView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
  println("you tapped on this \(recognizer.view) at \(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)")
}
```

Basically, clicking the dimmed view or the white part causes tapOnDimmedView to be called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the view with white color `view.userInteractionEnabled = true`